# Code folding is not saved in Spyder 5.1.5

Tags: spyder

I use code folding in Spyder but after file saving, closing and opening the code is present but code folding is lost. However break points are saved. How to avoid loosing the code folding?

I use Spyder 5.1.5 with WinPython 3.9.5.0 and the programs are used without installation on Win10Pro version 21H1.

**Edit**

Now, 2 years after posting this question, we have Spyder 5.5.0, which is still not able to save code folding. Imagine 1000 lines of code with 20 parts hidden inside. After closing your file or closing Spyder, you lose your structure and have to hide each part again.

An implementation is so easy as one only have to store the line numbers that we click if we want to hide some text. After opening the file, Spyder opens also the file with line numbers (that can be saved together with the code or externally) and applies folding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry but we don't have that functionality in Spyder, i.e. Spyder doesn't save folded regions in files before closing them.

Comment: Always loosing the settings makes this function not very useful. Please add!

Comment: It's in our todo list to improve code folding, but it's not so easy as it sounds.

Comment: Is it meanwhile included? I see no sense to write large code without this functionality.

Comment: No, it hasn't, sorry.

Comment: Is code folding saved in the current version 5.3.2 ?

Comment: Sorry, adding this feature requires some big changes in our editor and we don't have enough resources for that at the moment.

Comment: Is it saved in current version 5.4.2? Without saving usage is in vain.

Comment: @granularbastard, sorry, we haven't had time to implement that functionality.

Comment: Just save in the same file or in an auxiliary file the line numbers that shall be hidden. Every time after opening is it checked for these lines.

Comment: Now we have Spyder 5.5.0 Can now code folding normally be used?